# Why is the API data is not loading even after using getJSON call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I want to do a simple click button function which loads the data from openweathermap API and displays it on a button click.
I tried to use getJSON and getJSONP for the same but the data is not getting displayed.
Here is my JS code:

```
function clicck(){
    var url="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=pune&APPID=998ccd9a6bca814795a4815ec5ea7c89";
  //  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=url;
    $.getJSONP(url,function(a){
      ("demo").html(JSON.stringify(a));
    });
  }
```

My HTML code for the button is :

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<button onclick="clicck()">kuyku
</button>
```

I know its a basic question but I am really stuck on it.Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean to target the element with the id demo and change its html? If so you would need to do $('#demo').html(...)

Comment: no such method as `$.getJSONP()` ... see jquery api docs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried your solution, and find problem with JSONP function. If provided solution with misspelled selector `$('#demo')` does not works, here the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lgnw1y2y/3/) using only jQuery ajax functions.

In case there are problem with http call from https. Please check solution I upload to my server. You can check it [here](http://ag.x14.eu/stack/01/)

Full code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf8">
        <title>Weather app</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>
            h1{
              text-align:center;
              font-size:30px;
            }
        </style>
        <h1>
      <u> Weather App</u>
    </h1>
    <button>kuyku
    </button>
      <p id="demo">location is:</p>

      <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script>
      var url="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=pune&APPID=998ccd9a6bca814795a4815ec5ea7c89";
    $('button').click(function() {
    console.log("here");
        $.getJSON( url, function( data ) {
          $("#demo").html(JSON.stringify(data));
        });
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And [here](http://ag.x14.eu/stack/01/index2.html) the version you wanted to achive with onclick attribute in html.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf8">
        <title>Weather app</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <style>
            h1{
              text-align:center;
              font-size:30px;
            }
        </style>
        <h1>
      <u> Weather App</u>
    </h1>
    <button onclick="loadData()">kuyku</button>
      <p id="demo">location is:</p>

      <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
      integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script>
      var url="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=pune&APPID=998ccd9a6bca814795a4815ec5ea7c89";
    var loadData = function() {
    console.log("here");
        $.getJSON( url, function( data ) {
          $("#demo").html(JSON.stringify(data));
        });
    };
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I understood that I had not used '#demo' while printing the result,but is there any problem with the onclick function that I used in the HTML?I tried to run your fiddle using my onclick function but my code fails.

Comment: Jsfiddle has problem with executing onclick functions in html code. There is no problem with onclick. It should looks like this with onclick:

    `function clicck(){
        $.get( url, function( data ) {
          $("#demo").html(JSON.stringify(data));
        });
    }`

Comment: jsfiddle has no problem using onclick...if you set the fiddle up properly

Comment: I copied both the codes you mentioned on codepen(where i am working)but it is not working for me.here is the link:  https://codepen.io/ryoko1/pen/QgjzQe?editors=1010

Comment: Have you add jQuery? `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

Fairly certain your issue is with targeting the element you're trying to update after you receive the data.

```
$('#demo').html(...)
```

will target the element with id 'demo' and update it's html based on the input.

Comment: Andrzej posted a working demo, your issue is both with the targeting of the element and with the method you're using to get the data.

Comment: Thanx aaron.Is the onclick function that I used in the HTML wrong or does it have a wrong syntax?

Comment: The onclick function is being used fine, you can read about it here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp.

Comment: I am not getting the answer even after editing my code.Can you just check it.Here is the code link : https://codepen.io/ryoko1/pen/QgjzQe?editors=1010